# Blob download blocked in iFrame via content security policy on Firefox only

Tags: firefox, blob, content-security-policy

Content Security Policy is blocking download of a blob (csv) in an iframe on Firefox only, this works fine in Chrome... Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I've renamed the domains to make it easier to understand the parent child frame relationship.

This is the error:

Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
resource at
blob:https://mysubdomain-prod.mychilddomain.net/4663b181-76a0-dd4b-a5b2-7bbb65fd9f38
(“child-src https://mysubdomain-prod.mychilddomain.net
https://*.myparent.net”)

Firefox 54.0 on Sierra
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried adding `blob:` to `child-src`?